# nodejs with polling mechanism on aws crashes every x hours without a clear cause

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, pm2

The post might seem a bit lengthy but please bear with me.

I'm trying to figure out for a couple of days now very mysterious behavior of my `express/node` app.

My stack is:

- nodejs/express (with `setInterval` polling `SNMP` endpoint)
- AWS (medium instance with 8GB EBS)
- amazon-linux
- https sever running on port `3000` (the whole app is running on it)
- pm2 (as a node process manager - tried foreverjs too with the same results)

  The server looks like this:

```js
let debug = require('debug')('server'),
    app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

process.on('uncaughtException', (exception) => {
    debug(`UncaughtException: ${exception}`);
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason) => {
    debug(`UnhandledPromiseRejection: ${reason}`);
});

let server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

The `app` itself contains two parts, HTTP routes handling API calls and so-called `roller` which is a class and it looks like this:

```js
class SnmpPoller {
    constructor () {
        this.snmpAdapter = null;
        this.site = config.get('system.site');
    }

    startPolling () {
        debug('Snmp poller started');

        timers.setInterval(
            this.poll(),
            config.get('poll.interval')
        );
    }

    poll () {
        return () => {
            if (dbConnection.get()) {
                debug('Polling data');
                this.doMagic(this.site);
            }
        };
    }

    // other super useful methods
}
```

The `poller` runs a function every `poll.interval` seconds.

`doMagic` method calls very complicated mechanism of polling data from different endpoints with a lot of promises and callbacks. It saves data to at least 4 different `MongoDB` collections, parsing and calculating different values along.

All is good here. The poller is working fine all the promises are handled, all the errors are handled.

I put logs to each and every callback and promise.

Now, the situation is as follows:

When I leave the app running for several hours, it becomes unresponsive. When I try to reach it using `postman` I'm getting `didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. It is definitely not 404 error. The request knows that there is something but cannot access it.

Also, `pm2` is not restarting the app, there is nothing in the log files, so it seems that it's not caused by the app itself.

I was suspecting `memory leaks` and `unhandled promises` but I checked it, and all is fine, the garbage collector is behaving properly keeping the app memory at around `40-50Mb`. I also got rid of all unhandled promises during the process.

I also ruled out `db` connection issues. Double checked if it's not happening on `app` losing the connection with the `db`. It's not the problem.

The QUESTION:

Why is it happening, I can not find the cause for a couple of days now. I have exactly the same setup running on `production` and it's not "crushing" there. (production is not an AWS server)

Might it be something specific to AWS, amazon-Linux?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What type of EC2 instance are you running on? Is it a T2 instance? And if so, what do the CPU credits look like?

Comment: It is T2 medium type instance, the CPU credit usage is balancing between `0.2` - `0.7` (max). The credit score doesn't go lower then `500`

Comment: Well that was the only AWS specific issue that might be causing this. Since that isn't the case it's probably time to start debugging the code. Have you tried running this locally to see if you can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Of course! I have most sophisticated debugging system I wrote so far :D, as the questions states, I'm logging all I can from the nodejs app. Nothing there that would make me suspicious. The problem doesn't occur when the app is running locally, nor on the production server (mentioned in the question). The production server is not an AWS machine.

Comment: "*there is nothing in the log files*" - then try putting more logs in your code? Where is the app spending its time when it's becoming unresponsive? Can you use a profiler (not just a debugger)?

Comment: Probably you are leaking/not releasing some sort of resource (like a database resource or file handle) and eventually your app runs out.  The TCP stack still responds to an attempt to connect, but your code can't actually create a response, thus you the type of non-response, but not a 404 that you get.  It is most likely that some part of your code is actually encountering an error, but you apparently are not logging that error.  I'd suggest you go through your code with a fine-toothed comb and make sure every possible error condition is logged and you will probably make some discoveries.

Comment: @Bergi "there is nothing in the log files" - I meant nothing suspicious. Yes, I was thinking exactly the same thing, that's why apart from debug logs, I'm handling *uncaughtException*. That should log all unhandled errors I hope?

@jfriend00 - I checked using *--trace_gc* garbage collector flat, also pm2 process manager is showing memory usage. Nothing is leaking. At least the memory of the app is not paling up. It stays between `40`-`50` MB all times. Can you think of any other resource that can leak ? I mean, *--trace_gc* would show memory leak from the database too I suspect ?

Comment: what service provider are you using for production. I am facing the same issue , Any updates on this one ?

Comment: @AmitKumar as far as I remember this is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317561/node-app-unresponsive-after-certain-amount-of-time