# Node app unresponsive after certain amount of time

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, pm2

I'm trying to figure out why my nodejs app becomes **unresponsive after 11h 20min**. It happens every time, no matter if I run it on `amazon-linux` or `Red Hat`.

My Stack:

- nodejs (v. 6.9.4)
- mongodb (3.2)
- pm2 process manager
- AWS EC2 instance T2 medium

Every time I'm running the app it becomes unresponsive with an error returned to the browser:

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Pm2 doesn't restart the app, so I suspect it has nothing to do with `nodejs`, I also analysed the app and it doesn't have memory leaks. Db logs also look alright.

**The only constant factor is the fact that the app crashes after it runs for 11h 20min**.

I'm handling all possible errors from the `nodejs` app, but no errors in the log files occur so I suspect it has to be something else.

I also checked `var/log/messages` and `/home/centos/messages` but nothing related to the crash of the app there either.

`/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` doesn't show anything specific either.

What would be the best way to approach the problem ?

Any clues how can I debug it or what could be the reason ?

Thanks

Comment: You're leaking something other than memory is my guess, maybe file descriptors. Try using netstat or lsof to see if there are a lot more open connections or files than you expect.

Comment: does it work if you use node directly i.e. without pm2?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn That seems to be it! UDP connection is not being released and nodejs reaches the hard limit. Not sure how stack overflow works, but can I accept your comment as the answer ? It's not confirmed yet, I need to spend one more day on testing, but seems like it! Many Many thanks! I spent hundreds hours on it!

Comment: I'll add an answer if you'll accept it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from the comment since it apparently led to the solution:

You're leaking something other than memory is my guess, maybe file descriptors. Try using netstat or lsof to see if there are a lot more open connections or files than you expect.

Comment: Thanks Willis! Just to clarify, `lsof` was the answer to all my problems. It showed me unreleased UDP sessions (by one of the project's 3rd party libraries) which was resulting in reaching file descriptors limit on a dev env server (where the limit was set to 4096 - standard for linux machines). My development machine (mac) has no limit, and the production server either has no limit or it is set to something much much higher then 4096.